SoCal (GZ 11A): Tree Choices for Fire, Drought, Roots PLUS cover
I just purchased a lot in the hills around Los Angeles.  LA is of course dry from about April to about November.  Thus, I would like to plant drought-resistant and easy trees that can grow deep roots to stabilize the soil.  (I believe there is groundwater deep enough, too.).  so far, so good: presumably this is what Cal trees evolved for.  there is no building nearby, so extended roots are not a problem.  like in much of the SoCal hills, there is also a brush fire coming through about every other decade, so the tree needs to be reasonably fire-resistant.
alas, here is what they did not evolve for: I also want great canopy cover for shade in the summer and fall.  my favorite trees are the Moreton bay fig trees, but they have shallow roots and, I believe, require watering and are not too drought resistant.  (Oak trees don't have great canopy, and CA makes planting oak trees punitive, in that it triggers painful rules and regulations.  Needle trees, like pines, are painful.)
I would love to hear some opinion what arborist enthusiasts would suggest.

The Canary Island Date Palm is very hardy and has nice foliage, and it doesn't grow too tall...but it appears to be a bad fire hazard and it is about to suffer more of the South American Palm Weevil, and already suffers often from a fungus.
